# Why $\lim_{x \to ∞} 1^x=1$ even though $1^∞$ in indeterminate?

Tags: calculus, limits

Why $\lim_{x \to ∞} 1^x=1$ even though $1^∞$ in indeterminate?
I'm genuinely not getting it.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Because $1^x$ is *constant* equal to $1$. This is the same as $0 \times x$, which is constant equal to $0$ and *is not* an indeterminate form $0 \times \infty$.

Comment: “Indeterminate form” doesn't mean “we can't know what the result is”.

Comment: It's best to not really think about expressions like $1^{\infty}$ or $0 \cdot \infty$, etc. The symbol $\infty$ is not a number, computing a limit is computing which value an expression approaches.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe but then again why $\lim_{n \to ∞} (\frac {n}{n+1}) ^n ≠1$ even though it is equal to $1^∞$?

Comment: @GreasyLlama Apply the definition of the limit and you will see. Also read the answer of J. Darne to understand why the form $1^\infty$ is meaningless ($\sim$ indeterminate).

Answer (score 5):

Well, the fact that $1^\infty$ is indeterminate does not mean that $f(x)^{g(x)}$ has no limit when $f(x)$ approaches $1$ and $g(x)$ approaches $\infty$. It only mean that you cannot *deduce* the limit of $f(x)^{g(x)}$ from the information "$f(x)$ approaches $1$ and $g(x)$ approaches $\infty$". For some $f$ and $g$ satisfying this hypothesis, the limit can exist, and be $1$, or $4$, or $\pm \infty$, or anything, or not exist. It turns out that for $f$ constant equal to $1$, $f^{g}$ is constant equal to $1$, and the limit is $1$. But the fact that you can compute the limit in this case does not contradict the indeterminacy statement.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
1^x = \mathrm{e}^{x\ln 1} = \mathrm{e}^0 = 1
$$

for each $x\in \mathbb R$. Hence, the function is constantly $1$ even before doing the limit.